# Wordpress Display Post Type in Multiple Columns

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need help with the below code.  It displays alphabetically in a single column quite well.  How can I change this to display in 3 columns?

A

```
 Apple 1
 Apple 2
 Apple 3
```

B

```
Beattle 1
Beattle 2
Beattle 3
```

C

```
Cattle 1
Cattle 2
Cattle 3
```

I want to divide the column into 2 base from the total post.

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('partner');   
$lastChar = '';                 

while($list->have_posts()): $list->the_post();
    global  $post;  

    $brandname = $post->post_title;
    $char = $brandname[0];                      

    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
        if ($lastChar !== '')
             echo '<br>';                       
             echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red;
                    color:white; font-weight:bold;'>".
                 strtoupper($char)."</div>";
        //print A / B / C etc
        $lastChar = $char;
    }                        

    echo '<li><a href="'.$post->link.'" 
                 title="'.$post->post_title.'"
                 target="_BLANK"    >' .
         $brandname.'</a></li>';                        


    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Improve code formatting, header wording.

Comment: Thank you prune. Do you have i dea?

Comment: @user3103905 check my answers

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thanks for your help, can you check the second answer i post. I add screentshot on it. The issue with that is not properly group of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Used `WP_Query` for get post with `orderby` is `post_title` and `order` is `ASC`

Other code is working fine Check bellow code

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'partner',
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'orderby'           => 'post_title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',

    );
$list = new WP_Query( $args );
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('partner');   
$lastChar = ''; 
if ( $list->have_posts() ) :
while($list->have_posts()): $list->the_post();
    global  $post;  

    $brandname = $post->post_title;
    $char = $brandname[0];                      

    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
        if ($lastChar !== '')
             echo '<br>';                       
             echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red;
                    color:white; font-weight:bold;'>".
                 strtoupper($char)."</div>";
        //print A / B / C etc
        $lastChar = $char;
    }                        

    echo '<li><a href="'.$post->link.'" 
                 title="'.$post->post_title.'"
                 target="_BLANK"    >' .
         $brandname.'</a></li>';                        


    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

> EDIT For display in 3 column

Declare `$inc=0` above the while loop

change this if bock with old block

```
if ($char !== $lastChar) {
                 if($inc!=0){echo "</div>";}$inc++;            
                 echo "<div class='colm'><div style='padding:10px; background:red;
                        color:white; font-weight:bold;'>".
                     strtoupper($char)."</div>";
            //print A / B / C etc
            $lastChar = $char;
 }
```

Add this style in css

```
 .colm{
        float:left;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 30%;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thank you for your reply. The code above is working and yours also. My problem is how to display it in let say 3 columns

Comment: Hi Ankur, Can you help me fixed the second answer, i posted screenshot of the result. The issue is It doesn't group properly.

Comment: @user3103905     Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125878/display-3-columns-to-be-read-alphabetically-down-each-column/38147013#38147013