# Display 3 columns to be read alphabetically down each column

Tags: wordpress, post, types, multiple-columns

I bought a wordpress template and try to modify the codes in the brand page to display 3 columns. below is the scenario:

Currently Display:

```
a | b | c | d
e | f | g | h
i | j | k
```

I want the display to Becomes

```
a | d | g 
b | e | h 
c | f | i
```

The codes below display the current one. Can anyone help me to correct the codes below to display the above scenario.

[image]

CODES:

```
<?php
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'partner',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',        
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
   );

  // the query
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
     ?>
  <section class="recent-posts clear">
    <?php           
        $lastChar = ''; 
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts('partner')->publish;
        $i = 0;
    ?>
    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $i++;
   if(($i % 3) == 0) : else : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
        global  $post;
        $brandname = $post->post_title;
        $char = $brandname[0];
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:24%; margin-right:10px;">
        <?php 
                if ($char !== $lastChar) {
                        if ($lastChar !== '')
                            echo '<br>';                        
                            echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red;
 color:white; font-weight:bold;'>" .strtoupper($char)."</div>"; 
//print A / B / C etc
                            $lastChar = $char;
                }   
                echo $brandname; 
            ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
    <div>Alternate content</div>
    <?php endif; ?>


  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code try to remove

```
<div style="float:left; width:24%; margin-right:10px;">
```

and replace it with

```
<div style="float:left; width:32%; margin-right:11px;">
```

Comment: that doesn't work. check the screenshot thats the current display.

Comment: your columns are 24% which should fit 4 of them wtihout a problem. However, you have a 10px  right margin. Try to reduce the right margin from 10px to something smaller. Preferably starting with 0

Comment: Hi Janvier appreciate your suggestion, but the issue is not the column width. the codes above are displaying 3 columns however it display a,b,c,d ... horizontal instead of a,b,c,d ... vertical

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You just need a little counting and an edit in your loop. See comments in code -

```
<?php 
$count_partners = wp_count_posts('partner');
$count_posts = $count_partners->publish;
$i = 0;
//get the number of items for each column
$items_per_column = $count_posts/3;
if (($count_posts % 3) == 1) { $first_col = $items_per_column + 1;
                        $second_col = $items_per_column;
                        $third_col = $items_per_column;
} elseif (($i % 3) == 2) { $first_col = $items_per_column + 1;
                        $second_col = $items_per_column  + 1;
                        $third_col = $items_per_column;
} else {
    $first_col = $items_per_column;
    $second_col = $items_per_column;
    $third_col = $items_per_column;

}

if ($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()){
     $query->the_post(); 

        global  $post;
        $brandname = $post->post_title;
        $char = $brandname[0];
    if ( $i == 1) {//for the first item start a column div
        ?>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; margin-right:10px;">
        <?php 
    }
                if ($char !== $lastChar) {
                        if ($lastChar !== '')
                            echo '<br>';                        
                            echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red;
 color:white; font-weight:bold;'>" .strtoupper($char)."</div>"; 
//print A / B / C etc
                            $lastChar = $char;
                }   
                echo $brandname; 
            ?>
        <?php the_content();
        if ( $i == $first_col || $i == $second_col ) {
        //for first and second cols close the div and start the next
            ?>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:24%; margin-right:10px;">

            <?php 
        }

        if ( $i == $third_col ) {
        //for the third col just close it up
            ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
        }

        $i++;
    } else: ?>
    <div>Alternate content</div>
```

Updated - changed the syntax a bit and moved the counter to the end of the while loop.

Comment: Hi @dg4220, appreciate your help. i tried it but it display all in 1 column.

Comment: See my edits had a typo. This: if (($i % 3) == 1) { $first_col = $items_per_column + 1; Should have been if (($count_posts % 3) == 1) { $first_col = $items_per_column + 1;
If there are any other issues I'll be able to test it more thoroughly a bit later.

Comment: Also, just check the counters and make sure the numbers are correct; make sure $i is being incremented, etc. I'll be able to trouble shoot more later but wanted to get you the correct concept

Comment: still it didn't work. it just display all in 1 column. thank you, waiting for you.

Comment: Updated to fix wp_count_posts() which was being called incorrectly (check the codex) Did you check the output of the counters? That would have identified the probelm.

Try it now if you have a problem output the value of the counters and make sure you're getting what you expect. If not, add more information about what you've tried, what the counter output is, etc. I've solved the stated question but I'm not sure I should be checking all your code for you?

Comment: the counter is okay, i think the incremental $i is not working.

Comment: Conceptually, you understand the edits I made, correct? I've updated my code to move the $i increment so hopefull that takes care of it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'partner',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',        
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
   );
$list = new WP_Query( $args );
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('partner');   
$lastChar = '';  $inc=1;

if ( $list->have_posts() ) :
echo "<div class='colm'>";
while($list->have_posts()): $list->the_post();
    global  $post;  

    $brandname = $post->post_title;
    $char = $brandname[0];                      


    if ($char !== $lastChar) {
                 //if($inc!=0){echo "</div>";}$inc++;

        if($inc%4==0){echo "</div><div class='colm'>";$inc=1;}
             $inc++;             
                 echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red;
                        color:white; font-weight:bold;'>".
                     strtoupper($char)."</div>";

            $lastChar = $char;
    }  
    echo '<li><a href="'.$post->link.'" 
                 title="'.$post->post_title.'"
                 target="_BLANK"    >' .
         $brandname.$inc.'</a></li>';                        


    endwhile;
    echo "</div>";
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Add this CSS

```
.colm{
        float:left;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 30%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Ankur Bhadania, all is working now. I just change the value $inc%4 to 1 and it display what i need. thank you so much.

Comment: Also i use masonry css technique to get my result as illustration above.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to achieve the result in 3 columns in a group vertically is the masonry css technique. Here is my final result:

[image]

```
<div id="masonry-container" class="cols">
<?php      

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'partner',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',   
'orderby'=> 'title',     
'order'          => 'ASC',
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ));

$list = new WP_Query( $args );
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('partner');   
$lastChar = ''; 
$inc=1;

if ( $list->have_posts() ) :

    echo "<div style='colm'>";

    while($list->have_posts()): $list->the_post();

    global  $post;  

    $brandname = $post->post_title;
    $char = $brandname[0];                      

if ($char !== $lastChar) {                 

    if($inc%1 == 0) {echo "</div><div class='colm'>";}

        $inc++;            

        echo "<div style='padding:10px; background:red; color:white; font-weight:bold;'>".strtoupper($char)."</div>";
        echo "<br>";
        $lastChar = $char;
}  
    echo '<li><a href="'.$post->link.'" title="'.$post->post_title.'" target="_BLANK">' .$brandname.'</a></li>'; 

    endwhile;
    echo "</div>";
    endif;

wp_reset_postdata();   

?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#masonry-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.cols {
   -moz-column-count:3;
   -moz-column-gap: 3%;
   -moz-column-width: 30%;
   -webkit-column-count:3;
   -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
   -webkit-column-width: 30%;
   column-count: 3;
   column-gap: 3%;
   column-width: 30%;
}

#contents .colm {
   margin:10px;
}
#contents .colm li{
   list-style: circle;
   margin-left:30px;
   line-height:25px;
}
```